# How to get list of compiled files from Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I have a `Makefile` of a project. It is valid, and it works: if I type `make`, I'll get a binary compiled in the current folder. I want to find a way to programmatically (from a script) get the binary's name or, if `make` produces multiple files, get full list of these files.

I suppose there can be three ways to do this:

1. to execute `make -d` or something similar and analyze its output to get filenames. How reliable is it? Will it work for all `Makefile`s or only for the most standard ones?
2. to call some special `make` command which cleans all object files, so I get *only* resulting binaries in the build directory. Is there such command?
3. to parse `Makefile`'s content and get all information from it with a foreign utility. Again, how reliable can it be?

I want to find a universal solution for any `Makefile`-based project but if there is a particular solution for those generated by CMake, it would help me in some cases, too.

Comment: The output of `make -p` may be more useful than `make -d`; it lists the complete makefile with expanded includes and all the built-in rules etc. This gives you the complete set of rules to work with. You then have to know how `make` handles inferred dependencies (the rules that say that 'given a target `target`, it can be built from `target.c`, possibly via chained inferences via `target.o`). Note that most `makefile`s can create a whole lot of targets that are not listed. If there's a file `source.c` in the directory, typing `make source` will usually work whether there's a `makefile` or not.

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting problem.  A question: what's a binary?

Suppose I have a Makefile which looks like

```
foo.pdf foo.aux: foo.tex
    pdflatex foo

foo.tex: foo.tex.in edits.sed
    sed -f edits.sed foo.tex.in >foo.tex

PRODUCTS: foo.pdf
```

(that is, not just a Makefile which builds an executable program).  Is `foo.pdf` a binary?  Is `foo.aux`, which is a secondary product?  Is `foo.tex`, which is an intermediate one, and which isn't a 'binary' in any standard sense?  Is `PRODUCTS`, which is a dummy target, but which is still the target of a dependency rule, even a 'binary'?  Thinking along these lines, I suspect that there's no really useful, even slightly fixed, definition of what a 'binary' is in the sense you appear to be looking for.  That is, I suspect that the question you've asked might be vaguer than it appears.

Therefore, it might be better to step up a level, forget about binaries, and ask if there's any way of extracting the dependency graph of a Makefile.  Once you've got that, you can look at it and identify those things which are a 'binary' in the sense you're looking for.

How do you get that dependency graph?  The GNU 'make' info page mentions dependency graphs, but no more detail, and in particular doesn't provide a way of emitting the one that it generates internally.

It might be reasonably easy, in fact, to simply construct the graph for yourself by analysing the Makefile.  And there we go – googling 'makefile parser' does produce a few hits: Perl only as far as I can see, but you can probably do something with that.

This is a long way of saying that I can't think of a nifty faster way (patching automake would be one route, if you were generating these Makefiles by that route, but your question suggests otherwise).

Answer (score -1):

It's very common to find, in a Makefile, a target named `clean` with a definition like this:

```
clean:
    rm -rf *.o core *.stackdump
```

Invoking `make clean` then causes this target to be 'built', that is all the files in the current working directory with the specified names to be removed with extreme prejudice.

This is, approximately, what your option 2 suggests; you could probably write your makefile such that `clean` is 'built' every time `make` is executed.  I think this will be easier than parsing a Makefile or analysing the output of `make -d`.  It's probably also an easy way for you to circumvent the problems raised in @Norman Gray's answer.

Comment: Ideally, I would like to be able to parse *any* Makefile, not only my own. It is similar to what an IDE does: it gets list of source files from a Makefile, and I want to get the resulting files without editing the Makefile.

Comment: If you really want to parse a Makefile start by examining the source code of a program that already incorporates a Makefile parser.  A program such as GNU Make.  Adapt as you see fit, that's what open source is for.